# How to search partial style in a map?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a map object and search a list of styles

***Example***

```
['.card','.card-custom']
```

```js
var miMapa = new Map();

for (let i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    if (document.styleSheets[i].href != null) {
        if (!document.styleSheets[i].href.toString().includes('.css')) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j++) {
        var value = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].cssText;
        if (document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText != undefined) {
            miMapa.set(document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].selectorText, document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j].cssText);
        }
        
    }
}
```

***Example***

```js
var miMapa = new Map();
miMapa.set('.card','{ flex: 1 1 auto; min-height: 1px; padding: 2.25rem; }');
miMapa.set('.card.card-custom','{ padding: 2rem 2.25rem; }');
miMapa.set('.card2.card-custom','{ padding: 1rem 2rem; }');
```

If i print a key

```js
console.log(miMapa('.card'));
//Result
{ flex: 1 1 auto; min-height: 1px; padding: 2.25rem; }
```

Mi problem is when i search a combined style for example:

```js
console.log(miMapa('.card-custom'));
//expected result
{ padding: 2rem 2.25rem; }
```

Comment: Why do you expect `{ padding: 2rem 2.25rem; }` and not `{ padding: 1rem 2rem; }` when both keys in the map include the referenced selector?

Comment: Because el main style is card not card2

Comment: But there is nothing in this call `miMapa('.card-custom')` that indicates that you are looking for .card (and '.card-custom' is not a key of miMapa). You either need to set all possible sub-classes as keys, parse the Map.keys() to find partial matches, or access actual keys in the Map – `console.log(miMapa('.card.card-custom'));`